# How to check if user can accept DMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a DM command that works and everything, but if I try to DM a person that has DMs turned off, `user.send('test')` gives me this error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user`

How can I make it notify me if the user has turned his DMs off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no property on the user object that would tell you if you can DM them. You can, however, wrap the `.send()` method in a try-catch block. If it throws, the message is not sent:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();

try {
  await user.send('test');
  message.channel.send(`Message sent to ${user}`);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);

  message.channel.send(`I couldn't message ${user}`);
}
```

[image]